# Find Distinct values ID Field based on Particular Field and Do Aggregation top of it- Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a following format which has duplicate ID field.

```
ID  PDE_ID  Curency

1   21  USD 35

1   23  USD 34

2   25  CAD 43

3   26  INR 33
```

When there is a duplicate ID field , we need to pick the latest record by PDE_ID column, and with the result we need to do aggregation like Sum, Min, Max, value_count.

I tried top_result and max, but both doesn't support sub-aggregation. So i can do distinct and latest record, but cannot do any aggregation(sum/min/max/count) top of it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever is stuck, pls find the below query:

```
GET dispute-1-2022-04-*/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "Duplicates": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "PDE.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "div_id": {
          "terms": {
                "field": "PDE_DETAIL_ID.keyword",
                "order": {
                  "_term": "desc"
                },
                "size": 1
              },
              "aggs": {
                "individual_sum": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "DIV_ID"
                  }
                }
              }
        },
        "max_cal": {
            "max_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "div_id>individual_sum"
            }
        }
        }
      },
      "total_min": {
        "max_bucket": {
          "buckets_path": "Duplicates>max_cal"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```